# Connect second time socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, socket.io, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app with Angular.js. I have 2 page templates in my app, namely login and chat. Each of these have their own states. On the login page, user enters their name and hit login. This makes the state change from login to chat. Here the user can chat with other users using Socket.io events. This works fine.

But in some case, user may want to disconnect/logout and re-login with another name. In such a situation, socket.io does not connect to the server and the application does not respond as soon as the login button is clicked i.e. when the application tried to connect to the server. Here is the code.

My Socket Connection Service

```
.factory('socket',function(socketFactory){
    //Create socket and connect to http://chat.socket.io

    var myIoSocket = io.connect('https://node-samarthagarwal.c9.io',
    {   
      'forceNew': true,
      'reconnection': false,
      'reconnectionDelay': 1000,
      'reconnectionDelayMax' : 5000,
      'reconnectionAttempts': 5
    });

    mySocket = socketFactory({
      ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    return mySocket;
  })
```

Code on my Login Button

```
$scope.nickname = nickname;
    console.log($scope.nickname);
        //sanitize the nickname
        if(nickname)
        {
          $state.go('chat',{nickname: nickname},{reload: true})
        }
      }
```

Code of the Controller for Chatting page

```
.controller('ChatController',function(socket, $scope, $sce, $state, $cordovaMedia, $ionicPopup, $ionicPlatform, $ionicLoading, $stateParams, $ionicScrollDelegate, sharedProperties, $timeout) {

  $scope.statusMessage = "Welcome to ChatterBox"
  $scope.messages = [];
  $scope.nickname = $stateParams.nickname;
  $scope.userData = {};
  $scope.reLogin = true;
  var COLORS = ['#f44336', '#E91E63', '#9C27B0', '#673AB7', '#3F51B5', '#009688'];
  $ionicLoading.show({template: "Connecting..."});
    if(sharedProperties.getProperty().isFBAuthenticated) // Meaning that FB Authentication is used
    {
      var user = sharedProperties.getProperty();
      socket.on('connect',function(){
        console.log(this.id);
        $scope.userData.socketId = this.id;
        $scope.userData.fullName = $stateParams.nickname;
        $scope.userData.displayPicture = user.displayPicture;
        $scope.userData.color = $scope.getUsernameColor($stateParams.nickname);
        //alert(JSON.stringify($scope.userData));
        socket.emit("onlineUserUpdateAdd", $scope.userData);
.....
......
.......
    }
}
```

I learnt that we cannot create two socket connections. What should I do here, so that I can create another connection  or reuse the existing one?

Comment: I would disconnect the socket on the destroy event of the controller so that the next time the controller is called, it re-connects with the current user.

Comment: I tried that also. I guess the $destroy event is never happening. The application just navigates between the states. I am disconnecting the socket on the logout button click. Still it is not working.

Comment: Seems like the $destroy event is being fired. I have put in the disconnect code inside it. But still, it is not connecting again. I guess, it is because the line `var myIoSocket = io.connect('https://node-samarthagarwal.c9.io` can only be executed once.

Comment: I would add two new methods to your factory, one to create the connection, and another to destroy it. The one that creates the connection returns the socket for use within the controller.

Comment: How do I destroy the connection? Some code will be really appreciated.

Comment: `socket.disconnect()`.

Comment: Not working. I expected `forceNew : true` to work, but its not working. I need a way to use the existing socket the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code to my Controller

```
if(!socket.connected)
    socket.connect();
```

This reuses an existing connection.